# What is the best browser usage statistics source?

Tags: browsers, statistics, google-analytics

I wonder about what source of **browser usage statistics** is most reliable and updated.

I've been using

- [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics) (with use of my analytics enabled pages)
- [W3 Counter](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)
- [Stat Counter](http://gs.statcounter.com/)

but they are too different (one from each other), that I cannot say they are very reliable.

Which source do you think can cover most of web usage to provide such data?

Thanks

Comment: Are you interested in Mobile stats providers too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wikipedia provides an updated browser statistics summary that includes the top sources and median of these sources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Summary_table

For most uses, the wikipedia **median** is probably your **best estimate** for accurate browser statistics.

Each of the main browser stats providers are not 100% reliable because they all use a relatively small set of web sites that may lead to a biased sample set of users. Depending on what criteria is important or how 'most of web usage' is defined, different stats may be more useful.

> If you don't trust Wikipedia, follow the sources provided and compile your own median.

Comment: you really think that Wikipedia informations are bussines-reliable source? AFAIK wikipedia is edited and managed by users who don't have to be professionals etc...

Comment: @Marek Sebera It's not as if the Wikipedia users are just making the numbers up. They're pulling them from sources, and linking through *to* those sources; that page is just collating information. If you have doubts about it(or any source for that matter), then it's *your* responsibility as part of your research to get further sources for comparison.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that everything, everywhere on the web is edited by random people, with no guarantee of accuracy.  Wikipedia is one of the more reliable places, since there is an established revision system.  However, they are still just random people, and that cannot be avoided.  A book is no better: I find more blatantly inaccurate information in encyclopedias than on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

[Netmarketshare](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?spider=1&qprid=0) offers an estimate of browser share, based on data from around 11,000 partners.

However, no browser usage source covers "most of web usage", as you put it. All sites that report browser use simply publish their own (or partners') browser usage statistics, which are unlikely to cover anything more than a very small percentage of Web users.

**As such, it's best to evaluate browser support on a site-by-site basis.**

Use the browser statistics of the website that you're developing for to determine whether or not you should support a particular browser, not the browser stats of other websites.

If you're building a new site or you don't have access to user browser data, support as many browsers as you have the time and expertise to develop for, and start collecting visitor data to build a better picture of your audience as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Browser usage is going to vary a lot depending on what kind of website is collecting the statistics. Stackexchange is i highly technical site and as such you'd very likely find IE6 scoring much lower than on an overall web average. If you were collecting statistics on some winxp blog it would probably score significantly higher.  just something to consider when looking at stats.